# Why can't a User Story be attached to more than one Feature?

Tags: agile, team-foundation-server

I'm using Features to document the features as we originally communicated them to our client at proposal stage. I now want to create User Stories that relate to the features so that I can  easily map our stories back to the proposal.

Many of the stories naturally map across features, but Team Foundation Server (TFS) doesn't let me give a Story more than one Parent feature. Is this because I'm "doing it wrong" or is it more a limitation of TFS at the moment?

Comment: Are you asking about a specific feature in TFS, or a general question about writing stories?

Comment: Mainly a general question as in the title.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there's no reason a user story can't be attached to more than one feature. However, most people seem to agree that's a bad idea. Best practice is to limit a story to a single feature -- it makes the story smaller, and thus easier to estimate, build and test. Perhaps that's why TFS is the way it is, to force you to stick to best practices.

Your goal shouldn't be to do what someone else says you should do, you should do what makes your particular team as effective as possible. If attaching two features to a story does that, then do it. That being said, unless you have a specific reason to do so, I encourage you to stick with the best practice and only associate a single feature with a story.

Comment: i.e. it may be an indication the story is an epic/too big

Answer (score 1):

In the TFS parent/child relationship a work item can only have one parent.  However, a parent can have multiple children.

From an Agile process perspective, a user story should only ever align to one feature.  I would suspect that either your features or your user stories are poorly-defined.  Perhaps your user story is too large or is system-oriented as opposed to user-oriented.  On the other hand, perhaps your features are too granular and should really be user stories tying into a feature at a higher level.   Would you be able to give an example of a user story that would attach to multiple features?

A feature should be a high-level functionality with a collection of user stories scoping out how the users of your software will interact with that functionality.  For example, "Login Functionality" could be a feature.  "Implement Facebook Authentication", "Implement Account Deletion", and "Implement Password Reset" would all be user stories that tie into that feature.